# What are ruby 1.9.3 dependencies

Tags: ruby, build, compilation, dependencies, libraries

I'm trying to determine the fewest packages that I need to install before installing ruby from source. I've dug through ruby source a little and I figured it might be faster to ask here.

Does anyone have a list or know how to dig up this information?

Comment: Which OS? as that will determine what additional packages you need to install

Comment: I'm curious what **all** the requirements are, not just the additional requirements.

Answer (score 1):

It's all in the READMEs...

For [Unix-like platforms](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/README#L67) including Mac OS, no extra requirement per say besides a C compiler (C89 is the official target, even for Ruby 2.0.0).

For [Windows](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/win32/README.win32):

- Windows XP or later.
- Visual C++ 6.0 or later.
- Commands:

  - nmake
  - cl
  - lib
  - dumpbin

This can be surprising, but libraries like `libyaml` or `zlib` are not required. Ruby will [use its bundled `libyaml`](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7375) if need be. If `zlib` is not installed, then Ruby will work, but `require 'zlib'` external library will not work.

RTFM for more details.

Comment: Actually, for Unix-like platforms, you need the development tools (cc, etc.) to build ruby from source, which may or may not be present in a stock system.

Comment: Maybe a better question would have been what libs are needed for a complete ruby install. Where all stdlib requires don't fail.

Comment: @NathanLilienthal: That's a different question. It seems completely theoretical and not useful. If the answer is not obvious to you, ask it in another question.

Comment: It's not really theoretical considering most people rely on rvm or similar scripts to install ruby for them and they install these things. Wouldn't it seam reasonable to have documented what ruby depends on?

Answer (score 0):

According to its gentoo ebuild: berkdb, gdbm, ssl socks5, tk, ncurses, readline, yaml, libffi, zlib, libedit.